# Upload Image AWS S3 Using ColdFusion 2016 CFC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, coldfusion

I'm trying to upload an image to an AWS S3 Bucket but the method I'm using is saying my Secret Key and access code are resulting in SignatureDoesNotMatch. I'm using this example as my point of reference. https://gist.github.com/atuttle/4658165 Thank you in advanced for all your help!

```
<cffunction name="uploadToAmazonS3">
    <cfargument name="fileName" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="contentType" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="data" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="acl" default="public-read" />
    <cfargument name="storageClass" default="STANDARD" />
    <cfargument name="HTTPtimeout" default="300" />
    <cfargument name="bucket" default="#getProperty('EmailAttachmentS3Bucket')#" />
    <cfargument name="accessKeyId" default="#getProperty('EmailAttachmentS3AccessKeyId')#" />
    <cfargument name="secretKey" default="#getProperty('EmailAttachmentS3SecretKey')#" />

    <cfset var dateTimeString = GetHTTPTimeString(Now())>

    <!--- authorization stuff --->
    <cfset var cs = "PUT\n\n#arguments.contentType#\n#dateTimeString#\nx-amz-acl:#arguments.acl#\nx-amz-storage-class:#arguments.storageClass#\n/#arguments.bucket#/#arguments.fileName#">
    <cfset var signature = createSignature(cs, arguments.secretKey)>

    <cfset var url = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/#arguments.bucket#/#arguments.fileName#" />

    <cfhttp method="PUT" url="#url#" timeout="#arguments.HTTPtimeout#">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="AWS #arguments.accessKeyId#:#signature#">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="#arguments.contentType#">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Date" value="#dateTimeString#">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="x-amz-acl" value="#arguments.acl#">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="x-amz-storage-class" value="#arguments.storageClass#">
        <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#arguments.data#">
    </cfhttp>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="HMAC_SHA1" returntype="binary" access="private" output="false" hint="NSA SHA-1 Algorithm">
    <cfargument name="signKey" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="signMessage" type="string" required="true" />

    <cfset var jMsg = JavaCast("string",arguments.signMessage).getBytes("iso-8859-1") />
    <cfset var jKey = JavaCast("string",arguments.signKey).getBytes("iso-8859-1") />
    <cfset var key = createObject("java","javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec") />
    <cfset var mac = createObject("java","javax.crypto.Mac") />

    <cfset key = key.init(jKey,"HmacSHA1") />
    <cfset mac = mac.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm()) />
    <cfset mac.init(key) />
    <cfset mac.update(jMsg) />

    <cfreturn mac.doFinal() />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="createSignature" returntype="string" access="public" output="false">
    <cfargument name="in" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="secretKey" required="true" />

    <!--- Replace "\n" with "chr(10) to get a correct digest --->
    <cfset var fixedData = replace(arguments.in,"\n", chr(10), "all") />
    <!--- Calculate the hash of the information --->
    <cfset var digest = HMAC_SHA1(arguments.secretKey,fixedData) />
    <!--- fix the returned data to be a proper signature --->
    <cfset var signature = ToBase64(digest) />

    <cfreturn signature />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Cffile action=upload will work on S3. Why are you trying to do it in such a convoluted way?

Comment: @JackPilowsky 've tried <cffile action="upload" source="/Users/me/Downloads/1.pdf" destination="s3://#arguments.accessKeyId#:#arguments.secretK‌​ey#@cdn.website.com/‌​photos/1.pdf" /> but I get an error "The files upload action requires forms to use enctype="multipart/form-data"." Any suggestions would be greatly apprecaited!

Comment: (Edit) @ChaseCabrera - Action=upload assumes you want to take the result of a <form> post (containing a file upload) and post the file to S3 on the action page. Is that what you are trying to do? If not, try action=copy, FileCopy(source, destination), etcetera: This overview is for CF9, but should give you the gist: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2010/07/15/CF901-Guide-to-Amazon-S3-support-in-ColdFusion-901/

Comment: If you do it the <cffile> way, you don't need your S3 creds in the destination attribute.  Put those in the Application.cfc config, eg. this.s3 = {accessKeyId="",awsSecretKey=""};

your form that uploads the file needs the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute.

Comment: @ChaseCabrera http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274768/how-to-upload-image-in-aws-s3-in-cold-fusion